# Path Intersection Removing excess path

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, user-controls, windows-phone-8

Hej

Lets say I have a cirkel as my usercontrol in a Windows Phone 8 application, And I add elements inside a Geometry group, with a rectangel and a line. I would get the following:

[image: a usercontrol]
<sub>(source: [c-sharpcorner.com](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/path-in-wpf/Images/PathImg2.gif))</sub>

I am interested in having my cirkel as the main element. To specify I want the everything else to only be displayed in the region of the cirkel.
So if the rectangle was red I would only get the red corner displayed.

I have code that can manage inserting and moving objects. But I do not know how to make the intersect work opporsit of the picture.

I have tried a bit of the same in a small sample as is done in this link:
the link is http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/path-in-wpf/

Anybody has an idea for this?

**Best**
So the Best solution I found is to convert your element to WriteableBitmap, and then setting this as the background of your wished shape.

Comment: I really wish that users who down vote other users' questions would just take a few seconds to explain why they felt a down vote was necessary. How can anyone ever learn when they are not given any reasons as to what they did wrong? We have to remember... not *everyone* is from England and speaks perfect English.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain what I should change?
I cannot show code more than what is in the link. So that is why I wanted to explain. Something I should change? Explain more?

Comment: I didn't downvote (yet?) but as the question stands it's a bit unclear what is being asked, there is no code of what has been tried/fiddle, image to show what the user control looks like etc.

Comment: Okay, I will add this then. But it was more a general question since I was looking for way to accomplish something. I will edit right away. Thank you.

Comment: Yes JTIM, users here really like to see what you've tried (in code). If you haven't tried anything yet, then just have a go and then come back and show something... anything. To be clear, do you want to know how to get rid off the part of the `Path` that lies outside of your `UserControl`? If yes, I'd add that line to your question to make it clearer, and if no, then please explain.

Comment: I add a another element to my usercontrol that users can manipulate. But as I will later convert the usercontrol to an bitmap. I am only interested in having the element shown that is inside the usercontrols area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to acheive the above if you have the elements as geometric shapes you can use this link to get the path of the object.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/path-in-wpf/